# WordPress customizer Preview not loading

Tags: customization, wp-admin, wp-debug, wp-error

I'm creating a WordPress website, today I have tried to add some new features but I'm not able to add because customizer live preview is not loading

**I have done some steps**

1. Update all theme and plugin
2. uninstall all the plugin after some time again install all plugin one by one.
   3)Take a back up of whole site and reset the website by "WP reset plugin" upload again after sometime.
3. Check the hosting space but not the space problem.
4. check computer process is working good.
5. try to edit with mobile and computer both.

but still I'm not able to customize my website because problem is not solved.
Can you help me to solve it?

[Check my website](https://Bestmobileunderin.com)

Answer (score 0):

(I am allowed to answer but I am not allowed to comment, so, yeah.)

Have you made any changes to the .htaccess or added any .htaccess files?

**EDIT:**

We might need more information than that.

- **First:** Have a look here how to use WP_DEBUG: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/.
- Have a look inside `wp-config.php`, there is a line `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );`. Set this to `true` to turn WP_DEBUG on (and to `false` to turn it off again).
- Once WP_DEBUG is on, go to the customizer where it shows either the customizer, or a blank page, or maybe even a PHP error.
- If there is a PHP error, please post that error here and turn WP_DEBUG off again.
- If there is no PHP error, have a look inside the page source code, maybe there is a PHP error at the end of the file which is not shown by the browser because of missing HTML closing tags or something. Again, post that error here and turn WP_DEBUG off again.
- Also (while you have the customizer open) open JavaScript console in the developer tools of your browser, reload the page and check for errors or warnings in there and post the errors here.
- Do not forget to turn WP_DEBUG off again!

Comment: Bottondcs, No I have not make any changes in .htaccess

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information, i got solve my problem Although I had already updated my WordPress version, but I thought the same thing again by looking at the update and I did, My Customizer started working as soon as I updated.